# Why does the concentration of the acid equals that of the base at the mid-point of titration?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, ph, titration

Consider this graph of the titration of a weak acid and a strong base:

[image: Graph of the titration of a weak acid and a strong base]

The buffering region is strongest at the midpoint of titration because there is equal concentrations of acetic acid and its conjugate base.

> My question is why at the midpoint of titration does the concentration of the acid equal the concentration of its conjugate base? Also, why does the $\mathrm{p}K_{a}$ of the acid = the $\mathrm{pH}$ at this point?

Comment: Using as an example the monoprotic acid HA, by definition the pKa of HA  is the pH at which $\ce{[HA] = [A-]}$.

Comment: Can you explain it please, I don't know what happens. @Karl

Comment: A + B -> C, OK?  How much B do you have to add so that A is eqal to C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the midpoint of titration, the concentration of acid is just **approximately** equal to its conjugated base, as there must be considered the acid dissociation and ( in less extend ) salt hydrolysis.

If we take the definition(simplified using concentrations):

$$K_\mathrm{a}=\frac {\ce{[H+][A-]}}{\ce{[HA]}}$$

we can see that by definition:

$$\mathrm{pH}=\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \log { \frac {\ce{[A-]}}{\ce{[HA]}}}$$

$\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ is $\mathrm{pH}$ when both items of the conjugate pair have the same concentration.

$\mathrm{pH}$ near titration midpoint is **approximately** equal

$$\mathrm{pH}=\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \log { \frac {n_\mathrm{base}}{
n_\mathrm{acid, init} - n_\mathrm{base}
}}$$

This function has minimal slope = maximal buffer capacity at $$n_\mathrm{acid, init} = 2 \cdot n_\mathrm{base}$$

Comment: But still, why is just in the midpoint that the acid is equal to the base?

Comment: @Positron12 If you pass a half of your journey, does  the passed segment have the same length as the remaining one, or different ? At the midpoint, the half of acid is neutralized, forming the salt, which is its conjugated base, being in ratio 1:1 to the acid.

Comment: Then the same should apply at the equivalence point, why doesn't pKa = pH at it then?

Comment: Why should it ? Is at the equivalence the acid/base conjugated pair at 1:1 ratio ? There is almost no acid there.